# index out of bounds error: Python

Tags: python

In a code I was writing, I keep getting the index error "index out of bounds" however, I don't see a reasonable way that it would give me the error.

Here is where I get this error:

```
def data_point(box_size): 
    np.random.seed(250)
    x_data = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 40)*box_size*0.5
    y_data = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 40)*box_size*0.5
    for i in x_data:
        print "(", x_data[i], ",", y_data[i], ")" 
    return x_data, y_data
```

This is a part of code that I am using. Whenever I run this I get an error from the fifth line here. If I just simply put range(40) instead the error goes away. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` is not an index. `i` is *the data itself*. If you wanted to pair up the arrays, just use `zip()`:

```
for x, y in zip(x_data, y_data):
    print "(", x, ",", y, ")"
```

For cases where you need an index, you can use the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to *add* an index:

```
for i, x in enumerate(x_data):
    print "(", x, ",", y_data[i], ")"
```

or you can use `range()` with `len()` to produce a certain number of indices:

```
for i in range(len(x_data)):
```

Comment: Well, that was quite obvious I guess, however, I was able to use it in such a way:

`dx = x_data.copy()
    dx[:] = [i - X for i in dx]`

However, this works OK. I guess they are not the same thing.

Comment: Wouldn't `xrange` be better suited?

Comment: `xrange()` is indeed a good idea on Python 2 and especially if the number of elements is large. In most cases, however, you don't need a range at all. I used `range()` to echo the original code.